# How to fix textView.resignFirstResponder() crash in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Very simple program that brings up a num-pad which I want to dismiss when the user click off it.

I have
    ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate

```
inputField.delegate = self
```

and

```
inputField.resignFirstResponder() inside of touchesBegan
```

however the app crashes in the simulator whenever I touch outside of the num-pad.

I've tried putting inputField.resignFirstResponder() inside the button action, which is now also triggering the crash (only if the num-pad has first been brought up).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        inputField.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
        inputField.resignFirstResponder()

        outputLabel.text = "Your stamp duty will be: £1,750"
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        inputField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following in the debugger:

```
2019-06-08 17:23:19.945120+0100 StampDutyCalc[2104:180233] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

2019-06-08 17:23:19.976471+0100 StampDutyCalc[2104:180233] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 20615_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

2019-06-08 17:23:20.834475+0100 StampDutyCalc[2104:180233] -[StampDutyCalc.ViewController inputField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb26c517040

2019-06-08 17:23:20.844880+0100 StampDutyCalc[2104:180233] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StampDutyCalc.ViewController inputField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb26c517040'
```

Comment: Search on "unrecognized selector".

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to override `touchesBegan`. You might want to just use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Here's the extension I use to dismiss keyboard when the user taps elsewhere:

```
extension UIViewController {
    /// Hides the keyboard when you tap anywhere in the view that doesnt have its own tap recognizer. Ex: the view behind a button or text field.
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Now just call:

```
MyViewController.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
```

Alternatively, you could just apply that code directly on your VC, but I like to use an extension for reuse purposes.